# How can I remove an object with a foreign primary key in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa, entity, eclipselink

I was always told that in case of a bidirectional relationship that you remove your entity as follows:

1. Breakdown relationships
2. Update owner entity
3. Remove entities

But now my primary key is part of the relationship, so this isn't possible anymore.

Does anyone have an idea about how to remove the entity with the primary foreign key in this case?

I have tried to set the "mappedby" property to null and than just call manager.remove(...), but than there's always another entity-manager that still has a managed instance of the removed entity, so i get the following error:

```
During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship
that was not marked cascade PERSIST
```

Below i have put the code of the classes i'm using.

The class`OrderBill` here has the primary foreign key pointing to `OrderWeek`. This primary key is also a composite key sadly making the code a bit less readable, but it shouldn't have any effect on the issue i'm having.

```
public class OrderBill{
        @EmbeddedId
        private OrderWeekPK orderWeekPK;

        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumns(value = {
            @JoinColumn(name="weekNr", referencedColumnName = "weekNr"),
            @JoinColumn(name="yearNr", referencedColumnName = "yearNr")})
        @MapsId
        private OrderWeek orderWeek;
    }

public class OrderWeek{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="orderWeek")
    private OrderBill orderBill;

    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderWeekPK orderWeekPK;
}

@Embeddable
public class OrderWeekPK implements Serializable{
    @Column(name="yearNr")
    private int yearNr;
    @Column(name="weekNr")
    private int weekNr;
}
```

Is there some strategy for this that I am missing?

**Update**: for now i can circumvent the issue by switching the owning and owned side (transferring the mappedby to the `OrderBill` class). Now i can break the relationship without touching the foreign primary key.

This "solution" is still less than ideal: `OrderWeek` now has a redundant column (weekNr2 and yearNr2 for example) that is (or should be) identical to the primary key

Maybe this helps people with the same problem until an actual solution is found.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are using the MapsId annotation for. Did you just mean to mark this relationship as the @Id?  This would allow the OrderBill to use the OrderWeekPK  as its pkClass as well.

Comment: @Chris 
It is just to mark that field as a foreign key, saying the that field uses the pk of OrderWeek. ([This](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/26/jpa-mapsid-example/) site might explain it better)
But well spotted, i hadn't realized i didn't put an \@embeddedid for OrderBill in my code snippet here. That mistake might have confused a lot of people, will edit right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have done away with the @MapsId and embeddable within the OrderBill by using @Id on the orderWeek property and specifying @IdClass(OrderWeekPK.class) on the entity - this might work with your mappings as they are, but isn't the source of the error you mention in your post.

The problem is you have two entities with a bidirectional relationship. If you change the relationship (such as null it out), you are required to merge this change into the context.  So to remove an OrderBill instance, you must call em.remove on the instance as well as null out the OrderWeek reference, and call merge on the OrderWeek. This needs to be done in the same transaction, and while the change to OrderWeek's orderBill reference is a no-op in the database, it will keep the cache insync and prevent the OrderBill from being resurrected (or the exceptions you are seeing)

The alternative is to add the orphan removal tag to OrderWeek's orderBill property, which causes JPA to automatically call em.remove if you null out this reference.